# VBA - EXCEL - How to use a loop for multiple iterations, but also only one iteration?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Using the code below, I loop through worksheets and create an array.  Then I will execute an action on the array, in this case, it is simply outputting the ws names to a userform (for testing purposes).  The action will be to delete these ws, once I figure out the loop.

The two scenarios are: 1)  There may be many ws to delete, hence creating the array (95 ws currently).  2) The user may only want to delete the ws they are currently looking at; the active sheet.

*Why not just right click the ws and delete?  Because I'll already have a userform w/ numerous options to perform actions on the screen, so thought I would include this too.  Just didn't know how hard it would be to build this flexibility into the code.*

For scenario 1:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Del_WS_SeedAcct()
'Delete the individual seed account output worksheets, starting w/ "o_"

Dim wsX     As Variant
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim x       As Variant
Dim ArrayOSheets() As String
Dim wb      As Workbook:  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim j       As Integer

'create array meeting criteria
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ReDim Preserve ArrayOSheets(x)
    If ws.Name Like "o_*" Then            
        ArrayOSheets(x) = ws.Name
        x = x + 1
    End If
   j = j + 1
Next ws

'Action for testing
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = "Total: " & x & vbCrLf & j & vbCrLf & Join(ArrayOSheets, vbCrLf)
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
UserForm1.TextBox1.SelStart = 0
End Sub
```

This returns the correct 95 sheet names.

For scenario 2:  I tried this, but got "Run time error 438.  Object doesn't support this property or method." which I guess makes sense.

```
if scenario = 2 then Set wsX = wb.ActiveSheet
if scenario = 1 then Set wsX = wb.Worksheets

For Each ws In wsX
    ReDim Preserve ArrayOSheets(x)
    If ws.Name Like "o_*" Then            
        ArrayOSheets(x) = ws.Name
        x = x + 1
    End If
   j = j + 1
Next ws
```

I've done something similar before (reusing the action w/in a loop for a loop and single instance), but it wasn't with an array and it used a `FOR` counting loop.

How can get (trick) this `FOR EACH` loop into only executing on the active sheet for scenario 2?

Answer (score 0):

The active sheet is in the wrong place in the FOR loop.

```
if scenario = 2 then Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet


For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ReDim Preserve ArrayOSheets(x)
    If ws.Name Like "o_*" Then            
        ArrayOSheets(x) = ws.Name
        x = x + 1
    End If
   j = j + 1             'just a counter in this loop
Next ws
```

Comment: Ok... this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This works... not quite what I was going for - really just wanted to reuse the existing code in the FOR EACH loop.

```
'Userform
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        Scenario = 1                        'active sheet only
    Else
        Scenario = 2
    End If
    Del_WS_SeedAcct (Scenario)
End Sub
```

```
Option Explicit

Sub Del_WS_SeedAcct(Optional ByRef Scenario As Integer)
'Delete the individual seed account output worksheets, starting w/ "o_"

'or then move to its own workbook
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim x       As Variant
Dim ArrayOSheets() As String
Dim wb      As Workbook:  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim j       As Integer
Dim R       As String

If Scenario = 1 Then
    If ActiveSheet.Name Like "o_*" Then
        R = ActiveSheet.Name
    Else
        MsgBox "No output sheet selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ReDim Preserve ArrayOSheets(x)
        If ws.Name Like "o_*" Then
            ArrayOSheets(x) = ws.Name
            x = x + 1
        End If
       j = j + 1                    'used just to count the total # of WS
    Next ws
    R = Join(ArrayOSheets, vbCrLf)
End If

UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = "Total: " & x & vbCrLf _
    & "tot ws..." & j & vbCrLf _
    & "Scenario:  " & Scenario & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
    & R 'Join(ArrayOSheets, vbCrLf)
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
UserForm1.TextBox1.SelStart = 0
End Sub
```